Filing non-copyrighted patents to open source one's own technology; why, and how does one do it?
After about 07:52 in Johhny Harris's July 12, 2024 video The Problem With Elon Musk:

And Elon decided to make all of his technology open source. The patents were not copyrighted. Anyone could see them and use them with the hope that the market for electric vehicles would take off, and that the world would more quickly move away from the use of fossil fuels, which would ultimately benefit Tesla. - So if somebody comes and makes a better electric car than Tesla, and it's so much better than ours that we can't sell our cars and we go bankrupt, I still think that's a good thing for the world.

The video's description contains a link to the google document containing a plethora of sources, and Harris's videos are widely regarded as reputable.
Question(s):

What is the purpose and value of filing non-copyrighted patents? The video suggests it was to publicize all the technical details. Is that it? The patient application process - the system invented to protect intellectual property and effectively stop others from using it without our permission - is an effective way to do just the opposite - to open source it?
Is there, for example, a simple check box at the bottom of the application that asks "would like this copyrighted? Or is this just a word for a more complex process?


Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe these are not related and not duplicates:

What are the copyright terms on patents?
Are text and images in the patent copyrighted?


I'd definitely stop listening to anyone who talks about intellectual property and says  something like "the patents were not copyrighted". They've completely disqualified themselves.

@user2705196 ...from talking about patents. Who hasn't ever made a comment in passing about some side topic and found out later they'd used a word wrong? Well-produced, in-depth YouTube videos are hard, and since it's how folks generate income to pay the monthly mortgage or health insurance bill, they can't spend forever making them perfect. All the good YouTubers have small errors and mis-speaks. Give it a try - go make a perfect one and see if it's so easy. I think your comment is more drive-by manufactured indignant than it is thoughtful and helpful.

Tesla's "open source patent" claim is a bit dodgy really... as far as I know they have never released their source code... which is linux based and requires that they do so.  An off-the-cuff blog post that leaves this "good faith" term in there is also questionable.  You start building replicas of Teslas and changing the logo to "Bestlas" and selling them and... well see if Tesla's lawyers decide that's "good faith" use.  They've also sued former employees in the past for breaking non-disclosure agreements.  So that tells you a little about how open-source their philosophy really is.

if they make their own custom-OS from Linux source code, they also need to open-source it.  It's likely they also make use of other open-source GPL code in their own "apps"... but point being that I do not trust the claim that they have an "open-source spirit"

@browsermator OK, "source code for their linux-derived OS" certainly sounds like something that might-should be released. (I just invented a word there)

They clarify the "good faith" bit here:  https://www.tesla.com/legal/additional-resources#patent-pledge

@browsermator the conclusion of the video is that in recent years, Musk is no longer a good-faith actor (e.g. buy twitter to improve free speech and stop government censorship, then (according to the information given) do just the opposite (amplify Musk tweets x1000, ban Musk critics and Musk-critical journalists), but since "Tesla irrevocably pledges..." perhaps that pledge is future-Musk-proof? Anyway, thanks for the link - yes the terms are nicely explained there.

@user2705196 Not at all. The copyrightability of patents is a real issue. Review the core purpose of patents: in exchange for teaching the public about an invention, the inventor receives a monopoly for a period of time. The fact that the teachings are publicly available and exploitable is an important part of patents.

@user71659 Yes the concept of "teaching" is used in the preparation of patents, however, according to this answer it seems that a patent can not be exploited without being licensed, except "solely for amusement, to satisfy idle curiosity, or for strictly philosophical inquiry". That doesn't feel it rises to the level of exploitation to me.

@uhoh The teachings are important for when the patent expires. Even if it hasn't expired, one can use patents to draw inspiration for additional inventions: maybe a different method to solve a problem or applying the method to a different field. Perhaps a product performs poorly: one can figure out how it works via the patents and come up with a competing product that doesn't make the same mistakes. This is the same reason why academic papers are published and disseminated.

@user71659 Oh, now I start to see what you mean; got it. Thanks!

The claim is a garbling of the actual facts
Just as a spade and a shovel serve different purposes, a patent and a copyright are distinct. They're not interchangeable, just like a spade is not a shovel.
Copyrights and patents are both separate areas of Intellectual Property. Copyright protects the tangible representation of an idea in physical form, like this answer and your question; patents protect an invention, like the technical things needed to make electric cars work.
The YouTuber said "The patents were not copyrighted", which is always true. "The spade is not a shovel" is also always true.
What he meant to say is that even though Tesla had filed patents, which gives them the exclusive right to use them for as long as they last, they won't enforce that right against good-faith users - “Tesla will not initiate patent lawsuits against anyone who, in good faith, wants to use our technology.”
Legally, this is probably an offer to the world, anyone who accepted it, by "in good faith, [using] our technology", would probably have a binding contract with Tesla under which Tesla is obliged not to sue them. At the very least, Tesla would be estopped from such a lawsuit even if the agreement didn't amount to a contract.
Astute observers will note there is some wiggle room in the phrase "in good faith".
Now, the tangible representation of the patent lodged with the patent office is subject to copyright. However, copying that for the purpose of implementing the invention it describes when you have permission to use that invention is fair use of the copyright and allowed.

Thanks; to make sure I understand - there's nothing special about the patents themselves, their purpose is still to facilitate prevention of unwanted/unlicensed use of the technology, not to open source it. It's simply that the company has made public statements about their use that may be difficult to walk back, and have some ambiguity based on the term "good faith"?

When he talks about open source, he's presumably referring to the software that implements the invention, and design documents for physical components. They're allowing anyone to copy and derive from these.

@browsermator links to Tesla's definition of terms including "good-faith".

So as stated in the question, I can go to the patent office and possibly for a fee make a copy of all his patent applications. I can use them to find inspiration for my own inventions, but most not implement Musk’s inventions. Musk can publish his patent applications under an open source license, which doesn’t help me one bit because I am allied to copy them anyway. And it doesn’t give me any permission to implement his patents. N
